# Angular uib-datepicker-popup default date displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Sometimes a very, very simple thing gets way over-complicated. I have a datepicker popup set up and want it to default to today's date if no model value is available. I used the "initDate" config option, and that does set the default date in the popup, but not in the textbox where the date is displayed. To get the textbox of the datepicker to have the date, it seems one of two conditions must be met: 1. The model has a date value assigned. 2. User selects a date from the datepicker. This is unacceptable to me. Why include an option to set the default date, if all that does is highlight the default date's button, and doesn't display in the textbox?

The existence of this date in the model triggers some logic in the presentation and saving of the model, so it's not acceptable to simply set the model to a certain date. I need to supply a default date, and have that actually reflected in the widget, in the same manner as it would be had the model date's value been set. Can anyone help with this? It's extremely aggravating. This widget is very useful, has loads of excellent options and behaviors, and I've written up a controller that handles using this widget in a date range. The end of the range is where I want a default applied. Not an assigned value from the model, but a default. Any suggestions?

Per request, some code...

```
// Class for uib-datepicker config options.
export class DatepickerConfig {
    public formatYear: string;
    public formatMonth: string;
    public formatDay: string;
    public minDate: Date;
    public maxDate: Date;
    public initDate: Date;
}

// This controller only handles setting config options and disabling restricted dates. 
export class DatepickerRangeController {

    // You'd think the config objects would set the format for the popup, but that ain't the case.
    public dpPopupDateFormat: string;

    // Start/end date config objects.
    public startDpOptions: DatepickerConfig;
    public endDpOptions: DatepickerConfig;

    // Boolean values that indicate whether or not a datepicker popup is open. Setting this to 'true' causes popup to open.
    public startDpOpened: boolean;
    public endDpOpened: boolean;

    // Allow end of date range to be a future date. 
    public allowFutureEndDate: boolean;

    static $inject = [
    ];

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.initialize();
    }

    private initialize() {
        // Could have used config options to build this, but that's a pain. Only worthwhile if format 
        // is being built dynamically, as in supporting multiple formats. Only one format supported at present.
        this.dpPopupDateFormat = 'MM/dd/yyyy';

        // Basic config options. 
        this.startDpOptions = new DatepickerConfig();
        this.startDpOptions.initDate = new Date();
        this.startDpOptions.formatYear = 'yyyy';
        this.startDpOptions.formatMonth = 'MM';
        this.startDpOptions.formatDay = 'dd';            

        // Copy values to other config object.
        this.endDpOptions = angular.copy(this.startDpOptions);            

        // Set the initial value of these variables to 'false'. Popups won't open otherwise.
        this.startDpOpened = false;
        this.endDpOpened = false;
    }

    // Code truncated for brevity.
}
```

This is in TypeScript, by the by. Anyway, I thought setting the 'initDate' config option to the current day would do the trick, and in a sense it does, because the date highlighted on the actual calendar (the button) is the date specified by 'initDate'. But it's far different than when the model is set to a value, or the user selects a date. Here's the layout - I have a form with a date range, so I created this controller that takes in birth/death dates, and uses them to set initial date selection restrictions (minDate, maxDate) for the start and end dates. Due to a problem getting access to that object on page load, I pass it in as a model when either datepicker is opened. This same function runs every time one of the datepickers is opened, so it can update the restricted start/end dates when their values change. This let's me ensure no one sets a start date after the end date, for instance. I could handle my default date problem (badly) by setting the end date in the model, which would have exactly the requested behavior, but that would be a pain. I'd need to jump through a number of hoops. I can't simply modify the model itself, as this date is visible elsewhere on the screen (in a list view), and setting the end date of the model to today will make it look as though that end date was set, when it hasn't been. I could swap out a cloned object, but then when saving I'd have to check another property of my object and manually take out the end date based on that. This seems ridiculous just to set the default date in the popup.

Comment: could you share your attemp code.

Comment: What's problem with setting model of date field inside constructor? Why it's unacceptable to set the model with certain date? And it should trigger logic in presentation. If it's not triggering anything then it'll be just meaningless viewvalue which may be misleading & better keep that field empty instead. (And that's how init-date attribute works)

Comment: I have a list view that allows editing of certain values in an object. The end date is one of those values. Clicking an edit link loads an edit modal window. If I populate the end date of each with today's date, all the records would appear to have an end date set in the list view. Worse, it will save that value unless I manually remove it on save.

I could create a cloned end date, use that to populate the datepicker, and then do some checks to see if the end date was really set, and swap that out on the save operation... but that's ugly and I was hoping for a cleaner solution.